# HTML Form submit callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension to automatically log people into a captive portal on a certain wifi network. When I submit the login form, it redirects to another website. When I submit the form, I want the content script to close the tab by sending a message to the background page to close the tab. No matter what I do, I can't get a callback to work on `form.submit()`. I've tried the following ways to get it to work:

With regular javascript:

```
getSavedUserInformation((username,password) => {
    form = document.forms['user_auth_form'];
    form.fw_password.value = password;
    form.fw_username.value = username;
    form.fw_domain.value = 'REDACTEDFORPRIVACY.org';
    form.action.value = 'fw_logon';
    form.fw_logon_type.value = 'logon';
    form.lang.value = 'en-US';
    document.createElement('form').submit.call(form,function(){
        console.log("callback worked");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "closeTab"});
    });
});
```

With JQuery:

```
getSavedUserInformation((username,password) => {
    form = document.forms['user_auth_form'];
    form.fw_password.value = password;
    form.fw_username.value = username;
    form.fw_domain.value = 'REDACTEDFORPRIVACY.org';
    form.action.value = 'fw_logon';
    form.fw_logon_type.value = 'logon';
    form.lang.value = 'en-US';
    $("#hsFormId").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
        console.log("callback worked");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "closeTab"});
    });
    document.createElement('form').submit.call(form);
});
```

`

Also, I can't use the form.submit() function in the normal way since the form has a button with a name "submit", thus overriding the submit() function. That's why I'm doing the `document.createElement('form').submit.call(form);` way.

EDIT: I figured out a solution. I stopped trying to use callbacks and used window.onunload instead:

```
window.onunload = function(){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "closeTab"});
};
```

Comment: submit() stops any further code execution because the current page is going to be replaced by the response page from the server unless you're submitting via XHR.